# How to give only bottom border to RelativeLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a relative layout in which it requires only bottom border. How can I do that? Below is the RelativeLayout that I have used.

I have added view inside relative layout but it shows at bottom of screen

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#EAEAEA"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/auth_lbl_register_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="#EAEAEA"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:fontFamily="FNB Sans"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:maxLines="50"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="@string/auth_into"
    android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cellnum_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:fontFamily="FNB Sans"
        android:text="@string/cell_num_label"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/auth_txt_msisdn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cellnum_text"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="Enter cell number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/auth_cbx_agree_terms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:button="@drawable/check_box"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:fontFamily="FNB Sans"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="50"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="30dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="@string/auth_agree_terms"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- next -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/auth_cmd_validate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#F49B00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/next_arrow_white" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- end of next -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/or_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#EAEAEA"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:fontFamily="FNB Sans"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10sp"
    android:text="OR"
    android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/auth_cmd_register"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Register Online"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrowRight"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/line_arrow" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/auth_cmd_terms"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Terms and Condition"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrowRight1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/line_arrow" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: this is showing at the bottom of the screen because layout_alignParentBottom and the fact that RelativeLayout does not specify a height

Comment: please see my answer below, you must specify a height for the behavior your looking for on your Relative layout, setting layout_alignParentBottom with wrap_content will wrap the view to the bottom of the screen without doing so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `android:layout_height="N"` where N is your height in dp when using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutOne"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">
    <!-- Bottom Border shows -->
    <View android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#F00"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutTwo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text View 1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutThree"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text View 2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new `ImageView` to your `RelativeLayout`, set the height to 1 px, align it to the bottom, then this `ImageView` can be 'considered' as the border.

pleas see following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="55dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/labelColor"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/line_arrow" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBorder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:background="#ff0000"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

@inner_class7 is correct, you need to give a value as the height of the `RelativeLayout`, or, it will show on the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `View` to give bottom border to your `RelativeLayout`.

Add this in your `RelativeLayout`.

```
<View
     android:id="@+id/view"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="2dp"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:background="@color/black" />
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: this gives bottom border to whole screen instead of particular  relative layout.I have linear layout in which i have two or three relative layout.so what could be done please guide me.

Comment: Then add view to inner relative layout in which you want bottom border or show your entire xml file

Comment: you commented that "I have linear layout in which  i have two or three relative layout " so pls show entire xml file instead of showing just relativelayout

Comment: thanks by setting heigt of relative layout i am able to achieve bottom border

Comment: @berry shouldn't the accepted answer be the one i provided since none of the others actually explain that you need to add layout_height ...